# Add Columns to .csv from Multiple Files

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I'm trying to add columns to a csv file from multiple files. This is what I have tried so far, but keep ending up with either an empty file or just the column from the last file.

```
    while read i; do
        awk '{print $4}' ${i}.txt > ${i}_temp
        awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' OFS=, test.csv ${i}_temp >> test.csv
    done < file_list
```

The file list is just a list of accession numbers:

```
NA123
NA124
NA125
...
```

The text files that they correspond to have 4 columns in them, and I want to copy the last column and add it as the next column in a csv file. The contents of the files look like this:

```
NA123.txt:
April-18    10:00    18:00    8
April-19    09:00    19:00    10
April-20    11:00    16:00    5
...
NA124.txt:
April-18    14:00    18:00    4
April-19    09:00    15:00    6
April-20    07:00    16:00    9
...
NA125.txt:
April-18    10:00    22:00    12
April-19    09:00    12:00    3
April-20    06:00    16:00    10
...
```

```
test.csv:
0,
1,
2,
...
```

I would like the output to be:

```
0,8,4,12
1,10,6,3
2,5,9,10
...
```

What do I need to change about this or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to use paste and one additional temp file

```
touch temp

while read i; do
        awk '{print $4}' ${i}.txt > ${i}_temp
        paste temp ${i}_temp > test.csv
        cp test.csv temp
done < file_list

rm temp
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
 <file_list xargs -I % awk '
     { system("sed -i '\'' " NR "s/,\\?$/," $4 "/'\'' test.csv" ) }' %.txt
```

the `xargs` is reading filename from file_list file and feed to `awk` thought xarags's variable called `%` with `.txt` suffix as filename contains.

with `sed '#s/$/something/' test.csv"` command that used to append `something` at the end `$` of a specific line number `#` in a file like `test.csv`; so at above, `$4` is the string that need to appended to specific line number taking from `NR`; `,\?$` is saying might your line ends with comma `,` which I used because you have it in your `test.csv`. this `sed` command is calling by `awk`'s [`system()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function).

**note** that `sed` is writing in-place any changes, so you will not notice terminal ouput, do:

```
$ cat test.csv
0,8,4,12
1,10,6,3
2,5,9,10
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `paste`?

```
$ cat in1; cat in2
row1,col2,col3
row2,col2,col3
row3,col2,col3
row4,col2,col3
row1
row2
row3
row4
$ paste -d, in1 in2
row1,col2,col3,row1
row2,col2,col3,row2
row3,col2,col3,row3
row4,col2,col3,row4
```

Comment: OP needs merge column 4 from all files where their partial name is in file_list with test.csv file

Comment: That was not clear in the original presentation of the question which I addressed with this answer.